# Design a context free grammar language where length of a = double length of b

Tags: theory, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I would like to know if someone can help me designing a context free grammar

> for a language where { w | |w|a=2|w|b }

for example w=aab , aaaabb , aaaaaabbb ,baa , aba , aabbaaaba ...

S-> aab | baa | aba | SS | abSa | baSa | aaSb | bSaa would not generate aaabba.

So my next question is , isn't it too ambiguous to have a grammar that looks like this ->

**

```
S-> aab | baa | aba | aSab | aSba | aaSb |abSa |aabS | abaS | Saab | Saba | Sbaa | SS | bSaa | baSa | baaS ?
```

**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the grammars you posted can product `aaabba`, you need something like this:

> S-> HaSa | aHSa | aSHa | aSaH | HSaa | SHaa | SaHa | SaaH | HaaS | aHaS | aaHS | aaSH  | epsilon
>
> > H -> b

It can probably be done with a shorter grammar, but I think this will do.

Comment: Okay you are right I tried and I couldn't find a way to produce aaabba , but I have a question here , Shouldn't the epsilon be there ? Because S would produce epsilon and this word doesn't follow the mentioned condition , which is #a=2#b ?

Comment: It does actually `0 = 2 * 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
S  -> ε | S1 S
S1 -> ε | aaS1bS1 | bS1aaS1 | aS1bS1a
```